# Reading and writing string using Uint32_t

Tags: c

Using some chip, I am trying to save C strings , where the chip only works with Uint32_t numbers.

So to save a char array I use this :

```
            char data[]="lala"; 
            uint32_t save;       //save this to memo
            memcpy(&save, data, 4);
```

Then, when I read it I get a **pointer** to `Uint32_t` numbers where every number is a **string**(e.g first is "lala), and I have to extract the strings from these Uint32_t, but I get empty result :

```
uint32_t *data;
data = (uint32_t *) flash_record; //data pointer from some flash

//now loop over all numbers to read them:
   for (uint8_t i=0;i<flash_len;i++)
        {
                   char bytes[6];
                                   char n = data[i];
                                   bytes[0] = (n >> 24) & 0xFF;
                                   bytes[1] = (n >> 16) & 0xFF;
                                   bytes[2] = (n >> 8) & 0xFF;
                                   bytes[3] = n & 0xFF;
                                   for (int k=0;k<4;k++)
                                      printf(message:%c,bytes[k]

        }
```

How would I loop to extract the words back  ?

Comment: Why don't you memcpy() it back in the same manner?

Comment: Your edit just removed the parts that causes you problem. Please don't remove code that is crucial to understand the problem you have.

Comment: Hey, your code is fine, put it back. I just posted the answer ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Lundin how would I do it in the same manner? can you show ? Thanks.

Comment: `memcpy(there, here, 4);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
char n =  data[i];
```

it should be

```
uint32_t n = data[i];
```